# Run ansible jinja2-template as script

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Can I run an ansible jinja2-template as script directly on the client?

(Instead of copying the template first as file and then giving it the executable rights and then execute it)

Comment: How can you execute a Jinja2 template?

Comment: Well I meant instead of copying the template as file to the machine and then execute it in a second step.

Comment: Can you give an example? Because I never heard of such thing as giving Jinja2 template executable rights and executing it.

Comment: Well I have a template with dest that points to a scriptfile on my client.
After the scriptfile is placed in the machine I give it executable rights.
Then I call the script with the shell command.

Comment: I meant the script module

Comment: Whatever you meant, how and to what do you set executable permissions? Script module does not require it.

Comment: Oh I see you're right. Thanks

Comment: I asked you a question. Responding to a question with "thanks" is at least strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154763/discussion-between-marc-and-techraf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There's a [script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/script_module.html) module, but it doesn't work with templates – only with "ready" scripts.
But you can template your script locally and then use `script` module.

Comment: How would I template it locally?

Comment: Call `template` with `local_action` or `delegate_to: localhost`.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been an old topic but I'm just putting my thoughts in case anyone googled here. You cannot have template variables in the script, but you can pass template variables when calling the `script` module. So I'm suggesting you refactor your script and parameterize everything you intended to be template variables. Something like:

```
- name: call some script
  script: "some_script.sh {{ some_variable }}"
```

It's not every bit you asked for, but you also don't need two steps to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

The modern answer is **Yes**:

```
- name: Execute any_your_script.sh.j2
  shell: "{{ lookup('template', 'any_your_script.sh.j2') }}"
  register: any_your_script_result
```